# Black screen on notebook-display after Intel HD 3000 update

Tags: windows-8, laptop, intel-graphics, display-driver

I've installed Windows 8.1 on a Medion Akoya P6634 sporting a Intel HD3000 and a GeForce GT630M.

I had to disable Windows Update because the notebook's screen becomes black after it performed some updates.
Hooking it up to another screen via HDMI works but I can't activate the notebook's screen anymore.

So I tried installing the latest Intel 3000 HD driver manually (like described here https://communities.intel.com/message/248260). It says that the latest display driver is already installed.
When I install the Intel 3000 HD driver via the executable the screen becomes black after hearing the "device disconnected" sound.

When it happened the last time all I could do was switching to safe-mode and disabling the Intel HD 3000 altogether.

Installing the latest GeForce-driver has no effect whatsoever. All the time the notebook's display is running at a 1024x768 resolution (native resolution is 1366x768). It's using the Microsoft Basic Display Driver.

Do you have any ideas what else I can do besides going back to Windows 7?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall both the Nvidia and Intel drivers then only the drivers supplied by the OEM since only those supports switching between the two devices.  You have to decide which one you want to use.

Comment: Yes, I did. I had success installing the Intel HD 3000 vendor driver but it seems to be impossible to remove the Geforce-driver. Everytime I uninstill it completely via Device manager after the next reboot it's back again and I'm unable to install the old driver.